# Proper way to use LINQ with CancellationToken

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parallel-processing, cancellation

I am trying to write a LINQ query that would support cancellation using the [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) mechanism that is provided in the .NET framework. However, it's unclear what the proper way to combine cancellation and LINQ would be.

With PLINQ, it's possible to write:

```
 var resultSequence = sourceSequence.AsParallel()
                                    .WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
                                    .Select(myExpensiveProjectionFunction)
                                    .ToList();
```

Unfortunately, [`WithCancellation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413259.aspx) only applies to a `ParallelEnumerable` - so it can't be used with a plain old LINQ query. It's possible, of course, to use [`WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx) to turn a parallel query into a sequential one - but this is clearly a hack:

```
 var resultSequence = sourceSequence.AsParallel()
                                    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)
                                    .WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
                                    .Select(myExpensiveProjectionFunction)
                                    .ToList();
```

I would also like to avoid creating a separate `Task` for this operation, as I need to do this in several places, and I need to be able to control which thread this code runs on in some instances.

**So, short of writing my own implementation of `WithCancellation()` - is there an alternative that would achieve the same thing?**

Comment: I know this question was from a long time ago, but what was wrong with just using `AsParallel().WithCancellation(cancellationToken)` and just letting it be PLINQ?

Answer (score 36):

How about this approach?

```
var resultSequence = sourceSequence.WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
                        .Select(myExpensiveProjectionFunction)
                        .ToList();

static class CancelExtention
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WithCancellation<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en, CancellationToken token)
    {
        foreach (var item in en)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually worthy of being a feature request on Connect.

Comment: I'm not good enough to understand if there's any impact, or if this works or could work with AsParallel(), but I love the simplicity of this solution so I'm upvoting.

Comment: If I'll change it to `return en.TakeWhile(p_item => !token.IsCancellationRequested);` will make any impact on performance ?

Comment: It will be different as it does not throw any more. So if following code does not throw on cancellation, you may just get a partial result instead of "Cancelled"